# convergence of $\sum\frac{a_{n}}{n}$ if $\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{k}\le M*n^{r}$ where $r<1$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Show that if the partial sums $s_{n}$ of the series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_{k}$ satisfy $|s_{n}|\le M*n^{r}$ for some $r<1$, then the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_{n}}{n}$ converges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Abel's transform, namely, write 
$$\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{a_n}n=\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{s_n}n-\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{s_{n-1}}n.$$

Comment: Thanks for the hint, unforunately I still don't get it. I actually tried initially with Cauchy's criteria, and then using Abel's Lemma $$\sum_{k=n+1}^{m}x_{k}y_{k}=(x_{m}s_{m}-x_{n+1}s_{n})+\sum_{k=n+1}^{m-1}(x_{k}-x_{k+1})s_{k}$$ but I'm not able to finalize the proof this way...

Answer (score 3):

OK, this time I think I got it. So using mentioned Abel's Lemma:
\begin{eqnarray}
 & \Big|\frac{a_{n+1}}{n+1}+\ldots+\frac{a_{m}}{m}\Big| \\
= & \Big|\frac{s_{m}}{m}-\frac{s_{n}}{n+1}+\sum_{k=n+1}^{m-1}\Big(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+1}\Big)s_{k}\Big| \\
= & \Big|\frac{s_{m}}{m}-\frac{s_{n}}{n+1}+\sum_{k=n+1}^{m-1}\frac{s_{k}}{k(k+1)}\Big| \\
\le & \Big|\frac{s_{m}}{m}\Big|+\Big|\frac{s_{n}}{n+1}\Big|+\sum_{k=n+1}^{m-1}\Big|\frac{s_{k}}{k(k+1)}\Big| \\
\le & \frac{M}{m^{1-r}}+\frac{M}{(n+1)^{1-r}}+\sum_{k=n+1}^{m-
1}\frac{M}{k^{1-r}(k+1)} \\
\le & \frac{2M}{n^{1-r}}+M\sum_{k=n+1}^{m-1}\frac{1}{k^{2-r}} \\
\le & \frac{2M}{n^{1-r}}+M\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^{2-r}} \\
\end{eqnarray}
Now, $r<1$ means that $2-r>1$. So, as p-series are convergent for $p>1$, then for given $\epsilon>0$, one can choose $N_{1}(\epsilon)$ such that $\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^{2-r}}<\frac{\epsilon}{2M}$ whenever $n\ge N_{1}(\epsilon)$. Thus, if $N(\epsilon)=\max\Big(\big(\frac{4M}{\epsilon}\big)^{\frac{1}{1-r}},N_{1}(\epsilon)\Big)$, then the initial partial sum is smaller than $\epsilon$ for any $m>n\ge N(\epsilon)$, which means the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_{n}}{n}$ converges by Cauchy criteria.

Any errors here?

Comment: Looks good :-) (+1)

Answer (score 0):

Define
$$
A_n=\sum_{k=1}^na_k\quad\Longrightarrow|A_n|\le Mn^r\tag{1}
$$
Then
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=m}^n\frac{a_k}{k}
&=\sum_{k=m}^n\sum_{j=k}^\infty\frac{a_k}{j(j+1)}\\
&=\sum_{j=m}^\infty\sum_{k=m}^{\min(j,n)}\frac{a_k}{j(j+1)}\\
&=\sum_{j=m}^\infty\frac{A_{\min(j,n)}-A_{m-1}}{j(j+1)}\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
Independent of $n$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{j=m}^\infty\left|\frac{A_{\min(j,n)}}{j(j+1)}\right|
&\le\sum_{j=m}^\infty Mj^{r-2}\\
&\le\frac{M}{(1-r)m^{1-r}}\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$
And finally
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{j=m}^\infty\left|\frac{A_{m-1}}{j(j+1)}\right|
&=\frac{|A_{m-1}|}{m}\\
&\le \frac{M}{m^{1-r}}\tag{4}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, $(3)$ and $(4)$ show that $(2)\to0$ as $m,n\to\infty$. Thus, the series converges.

Comment: I'm very sorry, I just noticed that instead of $n^{r}$, it was written $r^{n}$ in the title of my question (the full statement of the problem in the body of question had it correct). So partial sums are not bounded, and for this reason Dirichlet Test cannot be applied. Apologies for your time.

Comment: @Crni: sorry for missing the difference between the title and the body. I have updated my answer.